# Do all elements have all properties 'applied' to them?

Tags: html, css

Do all elements have all properties 'applied' to them?

In the 'computed' section of Chrome DevTools there's about 354 properties when you select a given element.

Comment: Elements without specific styles will revert to default browser settings, if this is what you mean...

Comment: @Rmaxx No I literally mean does any element have all CSS properties applied to it? And is it the case that If the coder or user doesn't explicitly assign value to a property, the value is determined by the user-agent-stylesheet (browser)? And if the browser doesn't assign a value to the property, the property gets its initial value? I know there can be more steps in this chain (for example, inheritance) but is it overall right?

Comment: Well yes and no, they are all possible styling classes but they are partly dependent. Fi, a color style will only effect text contained inside an element and 'top' will only effect elements that also use position relative or absolute..or fixed.. anyway , it depends. And yes browser will determine default , which made reset css files a thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A div element, just to choose a random element, is part of an inheritance chain. It will inherit from HTMLElement, Element, and Node. All of which are defined as part of the DOM specification for HTML.

You can find the spec at w3.org (not to be confused with w3schools.com, which has a lot of misleading information).

Here is the spec for Node at w3.org: https://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/Node.html

These specifications define implementation rules for browsers to follow. The browser must choose which properties to populate during instantiation. Some are required, some aren't, and some are browser specific. This is true as well for css properties, which you will notice in the chrome inspection window as "User-Agent", which are also implementation specific to each browser.

Answer (score 1):

All css properties which can apply to an element do apply to that element.

For any given element, all css properties adopt their default values...

... unless a non-default style is explicitly declared for that property on that element.

Comment: Thanks @Rounin. Do all properties have a (potential) `default` value?

Comment: @tonitone120 Though I, obviously, haven't discovered all css properties yet, those I know about always carry their default values with them. :)

Comment: Sapinder is right, @tonitone120 - I can't think of a single CSS property which does not have a default value.